# Targeting the first and second values in a Class<Int, Int>

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin's [Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html) data class it takes 2 values:

```
Pair<out A, out B>
```

and those values are targeted via `first` and `second` named properties:

```
Pair(first: A, second: B)
```

However, how are the first and properties targeted if these properties didn't exist (e.g. for other classes with two parameters `OtherClass<Int, Int>`? - Is there another way to target them?)

PS: Why is `Pair` a data class and not a regular class?

Comment: Are you asking how the generic type parameters are inferred, in general?

Comment: For the p.s. It's a data class so that setters and getting, equals, hashcode etc is all generated for the class and properties. So first and second have setters and getters without defining them. As for the rest of your question I really don't understand

Answer (score 3):

A and B are *not* properties, they are type parameters. The type parameters are then used to define properties.

This is the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Tuples.kt) for Pair:

```
public data class Pair<out A, out B>(
    public val first: A,
    public val second: B
) : Serializable {

    /**
     * Returns string representation of the [Pair] including its [first] and [second] values.
     */
    public override fun toString(): String = "($first, $second)"
}
```

You target the properties (`first` and `second`), not the type parameters.

Suppose for example you have `Pair<Int, String>`. This means `A` is `Int`, `B` is `String`.

`first` is a property of type `A`, `second` is a property of type `B`, therefore `first` is an `Int` and `second` is a `String`.

In answer to your 'PS', Pair is a data class because of the [usual benefits](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) this confers, e.g. a generated equals() method.

Comment: type parameters, not type definitions.

Answer (score 1):

`Pair` repersents a generic pair of two values, think of it as a box with a divider in the middle. It doesn't care what you put in each side of the divider.

**What are First and Second:**

If you look at Robs Answer you'll see that Pair class has two public values, one is 
 name "first" and the other is named "second". It basically means that every box(Pair) 
 has two sides and it does not care what you put in either side, by default I have named 
 one side as "first" and the other side as "second" if you want something from left just 
 refer to it as first and if you want something from right side refer to it as second.

Doing `Pair("Some Words", 99)` simply means you want a box that one side holds a string and the other side holds an integer.

Doing `myPair = Pair("value 1", 100)` simply means you want a box that one side holds a string(value 1) and the other side holds an integer(100) and you have named this box myPair.

Since Kotlin does not care about the type of things that your putting in the box, than it is perfectly okay to add a null value to a pair, like `myPair=Pair(null, 99)`, its your job to check if there is a null value being added or extracted from the pair.

**Retrieving values:**

Say you do something like var `myPair = Pair("value 1", 100)`
  If you want to see what you are holding in myPair you can do:

```
println(myPair.first) -> "value 1"
println(myPair.second) -> 100
```

**Why is Pair a data class and not a regular class?**

The main purpose of a data class is to hold data.
Data classes have some restrictions so the compiler can add some standard functionality to all data classes, like eaquls(), hashCode()

Pair class is meant to hold a pair of data, therefore in can benefit from some standard functionality, like toString().

You can read the details [HERE](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at how `Pair` is implemented, you see that it's a simple data class with two properties: `first` and `second`.

```
public data class Pair<out A, out B>(
    public val first: A,
    public val second: B
)
```

As a result, you can obviously access these properties with this syntax: `pair.first` and `pair.second`. The names first and second are no special keywords but simply property names.

Note that there's something special about pairs and data classes in general though, which can be observed here:

```
val p = Pair(1, 2)

val (f: Int, s: Int) = p
println(f) //1
println(s) //2
```

This technique is called [*destructuring*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) and is made possible through `componentX` operators which are automatically generated for you if you use `data` classes.